# How to properly use Django's extra(select={})?

Tags: python, django

There is an object Foo which contains one value 'foo'
There is an object Bar which has attribute foo
I want to understand how to use Django's `extra(select{})` to get Bar object, that has foo attribute equals 'foo'

```
from foo.models import Foo
from bar.models import Bar
f = Foo.objects.all()[0] # value is 'foo'
b = Bar.objects.extra(select={"qux": foo="foo"}) # this doesn't work
```

`{"qux": foo="foo"}` produces errors. Something is wrong.

---

**Answer:** The correct code for me was:

```
b = Bar.objects.extra(select={"'qux'": "'foo'"}) # this doesn't work
```

So both qux and foo should be inside quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes. That's not valid dict literal syntax.

```
{'foo': 'foo'}
```

Comment: I tried it. The console produces error: 'Unknown column "foo" in "field list".

Comment: That's because you need to specify it as a string for the underlying SQL engine. `'"foo"'`